# Built-in animated "loading" image?

Tags: html

I want my html page to be as simple as possible.

Do modern browsers have a built-in animated "loading" (hourglass/spinner) symbol?

I know that you can change the cursor to "progress", but that's not what I want.

I want load a part of the page via ajax and while loading this part there should be an animated "loading" symbol visible (above this area).

I know that there are million of different spinner gifs available. But I would like to stick to modern html+css.

Comment: add a css transform rule to rotate something and remove the transform rule if you are done.

Comment: looks like there is no built-in loading animation. here is a nice and modern one https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

Comment: Have a look here https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps you may add and remove the transform rule by a timer as well  to get a infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers does not have built-in loading animation but here is a modern one for you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp